# Python class attributes from list

Tags: python, oop, attributes

I had a section of my code that worked to create 3 attributes of a class, `self.first_name`, `self.last_name`, and `self.email`:

```
    self.first_name = input("First name: ")
    self.last_name = input("Last name: ")
    self.email = input("Email: ")
```

And basically just noticed that I was repeating myself and could probably do this more efficiently using a for loop and a list of the attributes. So I tried this:

```
    attrs = ["first_name", "last_name", "email"]

    for attr in attrs:
        self.attr = input(f"{attr} :")
```

This doesn't quite have the desired effect, I think here every attribute is `self.attr` rather than the intended names. Can anyone suggest a way to fix this? I'm sure there must be a better way than writing it out every time.

Comment: Repeating yourself *unnecessarily* should be avoided. Abstracting away *every* occurrence of repetition is counterproductive. There's nothing wrong with making explicit assignments to distinct attributes.

Comment: I would not put the calls to `input` in an instance method, though. Pass values to be assigned as arguments, and let the *caller* worry about where those values come from. Exception: a good use case for class methods is to define an alternate constructor that handles user input and passes the results to a call to the class.

Comment: The loop is *less* efficient because you are adding the overhead of the loop and indirect attribute access on top of the actual assignments.

Comment: @chepner I agree that in this exact scenario, it wouldn't make sense to do this, but what if I had 50 attributes? And I had to do other logical operations with each attribute in the `__init__`?

Comment: Then you probably have too many attributes (or should be making heavier use of list- or dict-valued attributes in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

To be sure, there could be a multitude of ways to have a varying number of attribute and value pairs for a class.  Following is a simple proof-of-principle method using lists when initializing classes of people with varying amounts of information.

```
class Person():

    def __init__(self, attr_size, attrs, values):
        self.attr = []
        self.value = []
        self.size = attr_size
    
        for i in range(0, self.size):
            self.attr.append(attrs[i])
            self.value.append(values[i])
            
peep = []

while True:
    whoami = input("Do you want to enter in a person (Y/N) ")
    if whoami.upper() == "N":
        break
    x = 0
    att = []
    val = []
    
    att.append('First_Name')
    val.append(input("Enter person's first name: "))
    x += 1
    
    att.append('Last_Name')
    val.append(input("Enter person's last name: "))
    x += 1
    
    while True:
        more_values = input("Do you want to enter in more detail for this person (Y/N) ")
        if more_values.upper() == "N":
            break
            
        att.append(input("Enter additional attribute name "))
        val.append(input("Enter value for this attribute "))
        x += 1
    
    peep.append(Person(x, att, val))

for p in peep:
    for a in range (0, len(p.attr)):
        print(p.attr[a], p.value[a])
```

In this possible scenario, attributes and values are initialized in attribute/value pairs not unlike a dictionary.  This particular scenario does have required attributes such as first and last name.  Then, optional attributes can be included for each person created.

Following was a sample of output for the entry of two people with differing numbers of attributes.

```
@Una:~/Python_Programs/Person$ python3 Person.py 
Do you want to enter in a person (Y/N) Y
Enter person's first name: John
Enter person's last name: Doe
Do you want to enter in more detail for this person (Y/N) Y
Enter additional attribute name Age
Enter value for this attribute 66
Do you want to enter in more detail for this person (Y/N) N
Do you want to enter in a person (Y/N) Y
Enter person's first name: Jane
Enter person's last name: Doe
Do you want to enter in more detail for this person (Y/N) Y
Enter additional attribute name Age
Enter value for this attribute 64
Do you want to enter in more detail for this person (Y/N) Y
Enter additional attribute name Gender
Enter value for this attribute Female
Do you want to enter in more detail for this person (Y/N) Y
Enter additional attribute name Education
Enter value for this attribute BA
Do you want to enter in more detail for this person (Y/N) N
Do you want to enter in a person (Y/N) N
First_Name John
Last_Name Doe
Age 66
First_Name Jane
Last_Name Doe
Age 64
Gender Female
Education BA
```

As noted, this is just but one possible way to create various class objects with varying attributes.  Give that a try.

Comment: Thank you for this response, this seems to do some of the stuff that I want. But my focus is less on having a variable amount of attributes and more just being able to do the same logic on a large number of attributes. Ideally, I would still be able to call access attributes in the normal way using `self.first_name` for example.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```py
ATTR_LIST = [
    'first_name', 
    'last_name', 
    'email'
]

class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        for attr in ATTR_LIST:
            val = input(f"{attr} :")
            setattr(self, attr, val)
```